# Nodejs Express ejs view caching

Tags: node.js, express, scope, global-variables, local-variables

I have some problems with page caching. 
When user is trying to access restricted page with expired session or as unauthorised one system is redirecting him back to the login page. Additionally system puts error message into session store so it can be flashed to the user on login page after redirection.

I serve page from the express by rendering it with ejs like this:

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  req.flash('error').forEach(flash => {
  flashMessage += flash;
});
res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache'); //tried this for cache disabling. Didn't help.
res.render('login', { title: 'System login page',  flashMessage: flashMessage});
```

What I'm trying is to check if there is any message in session in variable `flash` and if it is I pass it as variable `flashMessage` to ejs rendered page. After that this message is deleted from session store.

However if the user refresh login page or even if I'm trying to access the same page **from a different browser** I still can see same error message. Even thought variable in session store is empty. 
I've tried `app.disable('view cache')` but it didn't help either.

Guess this is something with **express** or **ejs** cache but can't understand what exactly.

The only thing that helps is restarting whole nodejs app ) .

Comment: Do you have a reverse proxy (like NGINX or Apache) in front of your Node app? It doesn't make sense that the message would show in a different browser, unless something is really broken (for instance, you're using undeclared variables that get promoted to globals, or each user gets the same session id, which shouldn't happen with default setups).

Comment: @robertklep Yes, I have nginx as reverse proxy in front of app

Comment: Start by ruling out that it's caching proxy responses.

Comment: I've tested locally on my laptop (without reverse proxy or additional VMs. Still have the same issue. Even in a different browser.

Comment: In that case, run your code through a linter to make sure you're declaring all your variables properly. Express _never_ caches responses, `view cache` only caches compiled templates, but it will still execute/render those templates for each response.

Comment: Ok, you was right I'm not declaring `flashMessage` variable properly. It was outside the scope of `router.get` (became global) and wasn't cleaned after initial use. After declaring it with the scopes everything is working fine. Thanks @robertklep